# Why Spark dataframe cache doesn't work here

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe, caching

I just wrote a toy class to test Spark dataframe (actually Dataset since I'm using Java).

```
Dataset<Row> ds = spark.sql("select id,name,gender from test2.dummy where dt='2018-12-12'");
ds = ds.withColumn("dt", lit("2018-12-17"));
ds.cache();
ds.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).insertInto("test2.dummy");
//
System.out.println(ds.count());
```

According to my understanding, there're 2 **actions**, "insertInto" and "count".

I debug the code step by step, when running "insertInto", I see several lines of:

```
19/01/21 20:14:56 INFO FileScanRDD: Reading File path: hdfs://ip:9000/root/hive/warehouse/test2.db/dummy/dt=2018-12-12/000000_0, range: 0-451, partition values: [2018-12-12]
```

When running "count", I still see similar logs:

```
19/01/21 20:15:26 INFO FileScanRDD: Reading File path: hdfs://ip:9000/root/hive/warehouse/test2.db/dummy/dt=2018-12-12/000000_0, range: 0-451, partition values: [2018-12-12]
```

I have 2 questions:

1) When there're 2 actions on same dataframe like above, if I don't call ds.cache or ds.persist explicitly, will the 2nd action always causes the re-executing of the sql query?

2) If I understand the log correctly, both actions trigger hdfs file reading, does that mean the ds.cache() actually doesn't work here? If so, why it doesn't work here?

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to switch the order? First count, than write?

Comment: maybe it's because you append into the table where `ds` is created from, so `ds` needs to be recomputed because the underlying data changed?

Comment: @RaphaelRoth you're right, it's because I use the same table(even though I put data into a different partition). After using a different table, cache works. Maybe you can make this an answer, so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you append into the table where `ds` is created from, so `ds` needs to be recomputed because the underlying data changed. In such cases, spark invalidates the cache. If you read e.g. this Jira (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24596):

> When invalidating a cache, we invalid other caches dependent on this
>   cache to ensure cached data is up to date. **For example, when the
>   underlying table has been modified or the table has been dropped
>   itself, all caches that use this table should be invalidated or
>   refreshed**.

Try to run the `ds.count` before inserting into the table.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the other answer doesn't work. What I had to do was break lineage such that the df I was writing does not know that one of its source is the table I am writing to. To break lineage, I created a copy df using

```
copy_of_df = sql_context.createDataframe(df.rdd)
```